# Exchange Activesync/hosted website

Tags: exchange-2007, activesync

Ok sorry dumb question. If my website domain name is hosted, does that mean my root domain is unavailable for activesync? autodiscover.domainname.com resolves fine, would be nice if mobiles could auto setup, but they default to domainname.com, which forces a manual setup. 
**UPDATE** Here is the Exchange Test results...

Attempting the Autodiscover and Exchange ActiveSync test (if requested).
    Autodiscover was successfully tested for Exchange ActiveSync.

```
Test Steps

Attempting each method of contacting the Autodiscover service.
The Autodiscover service was tested successfully.

Test Steps

88Attempting to test potential Autodiscover URL https://hpsteaks.com/AutoDiscover/AutoDiscover.xml
Testing of this potential Autodiscover URL failed.

Test Steps

Attempting to resolve the host name hpsteaks.com in DNS.
The host name resolved successfully.

Additional Details
Testing TCP port 443 on host hpsteaks.com to ensure it's listening and open.
The specified port is either blocked, not listening, or not producing the expected response.
 Tell me more about this issue and how to resolve it

Additional Details
A network error occurred while communicating with the remote host.
```

Exception details:
Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 64.29.145.9:44388
Type: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Stack trace:
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Tools.ExRca.Tests.TcpPortTest.PerformTestReally()
    Attempting to test potential Autodiscover URL https://autodiscover.hpsteaks.com/AutoDiscover/AutoDiscover.xml
    Testing of the Autodiscover URL was successful.

```
Test Steps
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes as long as you can control DNS entries it should work. Autodiscover devices/software such as phone and Outlook should first look for the autodiscover xml file at domainname.com then will try autodisover.domainname.com.

Use Microsoft's Exchange Remote Connectivity Analyzer to see what's not working: https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/

Comment: ok so I just need to put a copy of the xml file in the root directory on the website? ...I meant to say the website is hosted on ISP's server...

Comment: No it would be better to point DNS A record of autodiscover to your Exchange server public IP.

Comment: Oh yeah I have this done already autodiscover.domain.com points to Exchange. However www.domain.com points to ISP server. So initial auto discovery fails at default domain.com and succeeds at autodiscover.domain.com

Comment: That is by design.  nothing wrong with that config, and most companies don't host autodiscover on www.  Are you still having issues?  I recommend updating this question with the full expanded details of testexchangeconnectivity.com

Comment: Good idea sorry. As you can see the initial test for the root domain fails because it is hosted at the ISP...  Second test succeeds (autodiscover.hpsteaks.com) because this is forwarded in my root zone...

Comment: So are you saying you still have an issue?  This response looks perfectly normal.  If you are having clients that still don't autoconfigure please post the smartphone details like make/model and the exact user experience and I can help you test.

Comment: Well any phone. Mine for example Sprint HTC Hero. In the Exchange account setup, it fails to detect so I'm assuming it can't resolve the root domain.com/autodicover because root domain is hosted at the ISP. So far all phones have to be manually setup which does work.

Comment: Yea you need to stop assuming that the root domain is the issue... I've set up dozens of working autodiscover networks and NONE have ever used the root domain.

Comment: Well I'm only making the assumtion because thats's the order of testing via Exchange Connectivity Test site. It starts with domain.com/autodiscover, which fails, then goes to autodiscover.domain.com. Phones work if I manually set them  up, so I don't have any confirmation of whether phones search in the same manner, or only search for the domain.com/autodiscover...